# nginx: try next upstream on http 200 response with custom header set

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx setup which works very well.
I am using an upstream block to load balance between two servers.
These servers give HTTP 200 response even if they unable to serve the request, but they set custom http header like this:

```
X-Response-Status: Failed
```

When the response is OK, they give:

```
X-Response-Status: OK
```

Is it possible to configure nginx to try next upstream server while the first one gives "X-Response-Status: Failed"?

I mean like following in nginx config:

```
proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_* ($sent_http_x_response_status="Failed")
```

Thanks!

UPDATE1:

I have to keep upstream servers giving HTTP 200 even on errors because there is an error message in http body in binary form.

I have to pass this binary error to client if none of upstream server are able to serve the request.

Answer (score 3):

There's no option for `proxy_next_upstream` to implement the behavior you describe.

Your application should not return an `HTTP 200` if it couldn't actually process the request. Have the application return a more appropriate error, such as `500` or `503`.

Comment: The application could process the request, but it gives error message in the body in binary form (another protocol embeded to http) If the respond HTTP 500 the clients would not process message body.

Comment: If the client is meant to receive the error message, then you shouldn't be attempting to proxy to the next upstream!

Comment: The client should get the error message if none of the upstream servers are able to serve the request.

Comment: @ZsZs Non-200 responses may still contain response bodies with the error message.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right, but clients (typically browsers) does not show these bodies but want to parse as for example OCSP responses. When a browser sends an OCSP request and get a non HTTP 200 response it does not try to parse the response body.